# Running piped bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, sh

I need to execute my bash script (output.sh) as piped script.
see below.

`echo "Dec 10 03:39:13 cgnat2.dd.com 1 2015 Dec 9 14:39:11 01-g3-adsl - - NAT44 - [UserbasedW - 100.70.24.236 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.65 - 3072 4095 - - ][UserbasedW - 100.70.25.9 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.65 - 16384 17407 - - ][UserbasedW - 100.70.25.142 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.69 - 9216 10239 - - ]" | ./output.sh`

how can i get echoing text in to my output.sh file and I need to split echoing text using `[`

output should be

`[UserbasedW - 100.70.24.236 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.65 - 3072 4095 - - ]`
`[UserbasedW - 100.70.25.9 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.65 - 16384 17407 - - ]`
`[UserbasedW - 100.70.25.142 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.69 - 9216 10239 - - ]`

please help me. i have no idea.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With grep:

```
| grep -o '\[[^]]*\]'
```

or with GNU grep:

```
| grep -oP '\[.*?\]'
```

Output:

```
[UserbasedW - 100.70.24.236 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.65 - 3072 4095 - - ]
[UserbasedW - 100.70.25.9 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.65 - 16384 17407 - - ]
[UserbasedW - 100.70.25.142 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.69 - 9216 10239 - - ]
```

---

With a bash script (e.g. output.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -o '\[[^]]*\]'
```

Usage:

```
echo "... your string ..." | ./output.sh
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: i need to get these output text into my output.sh file ... how can i do this ??

Comment: thank you... 
final thing can you tell me how to get following part 

`Dec 10 03:39:13 cgnat2.dd.com 1 2015 Dec 9 14:39:11 01-g3-adsl - - NAT44 - `

Comment: `echo "... your long string ..." | grep -o '^[^\[]*'`

Answer (score 0):

If it is removing *header* before first `[`, use a sed between before your pipe (assuming your echo is a sample of other source)

```
echo "Dec 10 03:39:13 cgnat2.dd.com 1 2015 Dec 9 14:39:11 01-g3-adsl - - NAT44 - [UserbasedW - 100.70.24.236 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.65 - 3072 4095 - - ][UserbasedW - 100.70.25.9 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.65 - 16384 17407 - - ][UserbasedW - 100.70.25.142 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.69 - 9216 10239 - - ]" \
 | sed 's/^[^[]*//' \
 | ./output.sh
```

Comment: how to write output.sh shell file to get splitted strings ??? i need to get splitted text into my output.sh file